# Projective representations of 1-loop quiver

Tags: linear-algebra, quiver

I study (finite) representations (over an algebraically closed field $k$) of the 1-loop quiver $Q$ which is defined by having a single vertex and a single edge. So, representations of $Q$ are just endomorphisms of finite dimensional $k$-vectorspaces. I need to determine all indecomposeable representations of $Q$, and by using the structure theorem of finitely generated PID's I'm pretty sure in saying that a representation $f : V \to V$ of $Q$ is indecomposeable exactly if the matrix of $f$ is a Jordan block $J_{a,\dim V}$ in some basis for $V$. My question is now: Which of these indecomposeables are projective? Here a projective representation $A : k^n \to k^n$ means that given any commuting diagram of $k$-linear maps as below with $\pi$ surjective, we should be able to construct a $k$-linear map $g$ (denoted by the dotted line below) such that the resulting diagram commutes.

[image]

I have tried to deduce some nessecery conditions for the maps in such diagrams if the representation is to be projective, but I have not been getting any wiser as to decide what I should think. My problem is that it seems (to me!) kind of arbitrary when representations of quivers are projective/not-projective so any ideas or hints as to how I could/should approach this problem would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your definition of projective.  If you are considering $A$, $B$ and $C$ as representations of the loop quiver, then a morphism from $B$ to $C$ is a diagram like the one you wrote, *but with $\pi_1 = \pi_2$*.  Otherwise, you are rather looking at a morphism of representations of the quiver $1 \to 2$.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon ups yeah of course. I guess similarly that the maps $p_1,p_2$ respectivly $g_1,g_2$ must satisfy that $p_1=p_2$ and $g_1=g_2$, right? After all, they are supposed to constitue a morphism between representations of the loop quiver (a fact that I now see that I did not explicitly mention). Then the problem changes quite a bit, I'll see if I can figure it out in this new (corrected) setting then. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) You are correct about $p_1, p_2, g_1$ and $g_2$, of course.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon I've been at it for quite a while now without making any headway. Do you have any suggestions how I could precede? In many poseabilites for $a$ and $n$ defining $J_{a,n}$ I have not been able to find any counter-examples while I still don't see why (and if) this should be projective.

Comment: I'll have a go at an answer later today.  May I suggest that you edit the question so that it includes the correct definitions?

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon Thank you! Yes I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your algebra is isomorphic to the polynomial algebra $k[x]$, which is a PID, let's answer a slightly more general question:

**Question:** Let $R$ be any PID.  What are the finitely generated projective $R$-modules?

**Answer:** The free $R$-modules.

To see why a torsion module cannot be projective, let $M$ be an indecomposable torsion module.  By the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over PIDs, there exists a non-zero, non-invertible element $a$ of $R$ such that $M$ is isomorphic to $R/(a)$.  Then there is a short exact sequence

$$
 0 \to R/(a) \to R/(a^2) \to R/(a) \to 0,
$$

where the first morphism is multiplication by $a$ and the second is the natural projection.  Clearly, this sequence is not split.  Thus the right-most module, $R/(a)$, cannot be projective.

---

Going back to representations of the 1-loop quiver: over $k[x]$, the finitely generated torsion modules are preciely the modules which are finite-dimensional over $k$.  Thus there are no projective finite-dimensional representations of the 1-loop quiver.

Comment: Okay thanks! Let me see if I understand this correctly: First, for a PID $R$ we are using the fact that the two notions "$P$ is a projective $R$-module" and "any SES $0 \to A \to B \to P \to 0$ is split-exact" are equivalent. Then, since the SES $0 \to R/(a) \overset{\cdot a}{\to} R/(a^2) \to R/(a) \to 0$ does not split (I guess since $R/(a^2)$ is not isomorphic to $R/(a) \oplus R/(a)$?), $R/(a)$ is not projective. (continued)

Comment: Next, since an indecomposeable representation of $Q$ given by $f : V \to V$ defines a $k[X]$-module by the data $(f,V)$ which is isomorphic to $k[X]/(x-a)^n$ for some $a \in k$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (this was what I used when I determined the indecomposeables), $(V,f)$ is not projective as a $k[X]$-module, and therefore not projective as a representation of the quiver $Q$, because the catagory of representations of $Q$ is equivalent to the catagory of $k[X]$-modules?

Comment: I guess this also shows that indecomposeable representations are not injective: Again using the fact that the SES $0 \to R/(a) \to R/(a^2) \to R/(a) \to 0$ does not split, and this time thinking of the first $R/(a)$ in the sequnce as our indecomposeable representation.

Comment: @JamieWinterNilsson That's right: we are using the equivalence you mention, and the fact that $R/(a^2)$ is in fact indecomposable.  Your second comment is also exactly right, and so is your third.